# Possible to integrate while loop into Android studio network connect?

Tags: android, http, while-loop

I am facing a small issue with the android studio net work connect sample code.

Basically the code does exactly what i need, Press a button, it will fetch raw html  a predetermined http.

However i was wondering if it is possible to make a while loop such that i do not need to press on the fetch button every time i want to get the data.

Regards.

http://developer.android.com/samples/NetworkConnect/index.html

Answer (score 1):

What do you want exactly ? Do you want to refresh the web page or to check network connection ?

It seems you looking for refreshing the web page some period time.

While loop doesn't make sense. I suggest you to use Thread Handler or Timer.

[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209078/how-to-refresh-the-webview-in-android-using-a-timer)
you may get some ideas.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

i need to retrieve fresh data from the webpage.
reason being that the webpage changes every second and i need to fetch new data.

Comment: if my post answer is satisfy your need please mark it as an answer. thank you.

Comment: what are you doing with that data ? please more specific. what kind of data you are getting ? or please share some snippet.

Comment: Its numeric data  generated from a webserver, i need the data to be displayed just like how the sample code does it but the sample code requires me to press the fetch button every time i want to get new data