# How to refresh Android WebView activity every 5 seconds?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have an android app that i want to refresh its screen every 5 mins for my website. Could anyone help?

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
    }

    public native String stringFromJNI();
}
```

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255478/9408181

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Android WebView autorefresh periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255214/making-android-webview-autorefresh-periodically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This
 Solution 1 :

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();

TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
@Override
public void run () 
{
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
}};
timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 0l, 5000*60*60);
```

Solution 2 :

```
public void reloadWebView() {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}, 50000);}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `reload()` method `onCreate()`

```
public void reload() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do something after 5min = 50000ms
                Toast.makeText(LogThirdPager.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reload();
                // mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        }, 50000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **TimerTask** for every 5 minutes like below"

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         if(webView!=null)
            reload();   // reload your webview
        }
    };
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0,300000); // 300000 ms = 5 minutes
```