# How to load Twitch live stream in android WebView Or Video player

Tags: android, twitch, twitch-api

I am trying to play live stream video from Twitch , inside webview but getting issue, when streaming was started after page load then it is not showing in video . i have to load it manually .

I am using this below url to load video in side android webView :

https://player.twitch.tv/?autoplay=true&channel=x2twins&parent=streamernews.example.com

What is the best way to play video in android , so that if streaming starts after page load then , streaming video starts autometically

Comment: check this out,https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255478/12709358

Answer (score 1):

You should use VideoView instead of WebView
If you want the stream to start playing automatically when the activity opens, call the play method in onCreate
Also save the latest states at onPause in savedInstanceState and read it again in onResume

Comment: I tried but videoView doesn't support Twitch link , i tried with above link .

Comment: You must use the [Twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference). If you have never worked with an API, use your own method (WebView). But know that the standard method is to use the API and the sooner you learn the better